# Understanding new operators

Tags: c++, new-operator

What happened if we invoke different forms of the operator new and operator delete?

```
class A
{
public:
    void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, const char* msg );
};

void* A::operator new  ( std::size_t sz, const char* msg ){
    std::printf("global op new called, message = %s",msg);
    return std::malloc(sz);
}

int main(){
    A *a = new ("message") A;
    delete a;
}
```

Does the program have UB in that case? What is Standard talking about that?

Comment: Can you guarantee that `delete` calls `free()`?  What if your overloaded `new` called a system function, for example in Windows `HeapAlloc`?  How is `delete` supposed to know to call `HeapFree`?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Because I didn't provide the definition of the `delete`, the operator will call the global `delete` deallocation function. So, standard can garantee the calling `free`, is that what you mean?

Comment: The standard doesn't guarantee how `delete` is to be implemented.  You have no idea if it uses `free` or not.  But again, you didn't answer the second part of my question.  How is `delete` supposed to magically know what the correct, corresponding deallocation function to call if you have overloaded `new` with a call to a function such as `HeapAlloc`?  So answering that question more than likely answers your question concerning if it is UB or not.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie But the standard does guarantee that __The delete-expression operator destroys a most derived object (1.8) or array created by a new-expression.__ I thought the ony way to release memory is to call `free`

Comment: `new' and `delete` are *not* `malloc` and `free`.  What if the call to `delete` adjusts a data structure that keeps track of memory allocated with `new`?   For example, there are "debugging" libraries that keeps track of `new` and `delete` allocations.  Your example has `new` blindly calling `malloc` without any knowledge of updating these statistics.  So what will happen when the implementation's `delete` call detects that your pointer is unknown and thus aborts the program (using `assert()` or similar function)?

Comment: `I thought the ony way to release memory is to call free` Wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code has undefined behaviour, in a number of ways.

In general terms, the result is undefined unless the form of release matches the form of allocation.   That includes a mismatch of form of operator new.   (Placement new is a bit special and different, but I won't go there).

Also, the OP's comments below the original post are 100% incorrect.  There is no requirement that any form of `operator new` or `operator delete` use `malloc()` and `free()` (or related functions).    Accordingly, the statement `delete a` has undefined behaviour, since it means that memory allocated using `malloc()` is released using the global `operator delete()`.

Comment: As I said, there's the guarantee that the objec the operator delete is called on will be destroyed. So, I thought the `free` function will be called

Comment: Moreover, the stadard specifies UB only if we call `new[]` and then call `delete` and vice versa. __n the second
alternative (delete array), the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value or a pointer
value that resulted from a previous array new-expression.81 If not, the behavior is undefined.__

Comment: And, as I said, you are incorrect.   There is no requirement that any form of `operator delete` call `free()`.

Comment: So, if `free()` is not called, what then?

Comment: That depends on the implementation.

Comment: You should not mix malloc/free with new/delete. See for example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6555/To-new-is-C-To-malloc-is-C-To-mix-them-is-sin